# How to bundle flex app apk and normal apk

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, apk

I have two different codes for an android app. One of written in java, and the other one writed in adobe flex. The funcitonality is different for both programs. But it serves like a one program. I mean both of them are connected and when necessary first one intending the second one. I have to bundle them and when the user installs this bundle, the flex one shouldn't has an icon. So how can it become to one apk and one icon with saving the intends?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to bundle two regular apks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest, each activity declared with a category of type Launcher has its own icon in the menu drawer.

```
<activity
    android:name="fr.hozakan.productreminder.client.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Remove the category tag on the activity of your choice, then it should be OK

Comment: There is no option to change these on flex. Just an xml file for adding permissions. But i built apk and open it with winrar. I saw AndroidManifest.xml file. But its encoded i think. How can i decode it? When i try apktool, it decompiles regular apk but built from flex apk's causing decode errors on AndroidManifest.xml file. What do you suggest?

Comment: Can't you remove the category from your other APK? I have never use flex, so, I cannot help you on that point. Maybe there is options with flex to handle more complex manifests

Comment: Okay apktool works. I have decompile it, and changed the manifest (category deleted). Then i build it again and it works partially. There is no icon of the flex app, but the worst part is now i cant intent to flex app from my first app. How can i start the iconless app programatically? Yes, flex app has it own UI.

Comment: Don't remove the category. Change it to another type one (not the "launcher" type)

Comment: Its solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771767/intent-to-hidden-application-on-android?noredirect=1#comment31133351_20771767